# i cant see SonarCloud result of my golang code

Tags: azure, go, sonarcloud

i'm new in devops, and Azure. I'm trying to use SonarCloud in my project with Golang in Azure. I already install the extension, the prepare analysis configuration, run code analysis and publish code gate quality in the CI pipeline. When i run my code CI everything do fine but when i go see the results in SonarCloud, apparently just the golang code its not analyzed. i can see in Sumarry 0 Bugs, Code Smells, Vulnerabilities and Security Hotspots, and in Code i can see just the Dockerfile, the pipeline yml and manifests folder.

I tried to install the golang during CI pipeline but not work. I want see my project bugs in solarcloud sumary

Comment: Share your CI pipeline details as well as how you configured the sonar configuration file

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.